# How to generate Tree structure by parsing the string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The original api response is as follows

```
 org = [
        { title: "New", count: 1 },
        { title: "Parent::Child::GrandChild", count: 0 },
        { title: "Parent::Child", count: 0 },
    ]
```

How can I convert a new object by parsing the title from the above response?

```
newObtj = [
            { title: "New", count: 1, child: [] },
            {
                title: "Parent",
                count: 0,
                child: [
                    { title: "Child", count: 0, child: [{ title: "GrandChild", count: 0, child: [] }] }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: "Parent",
                count: 0,
                child: [{ title: "Child", count: 0, child: [] }]
            },
        ]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: why do you want for same (named) parent different objects?

Answer (score 0):

You should take the time to think through how you want your new object to be structured.  To get you started, this is how I would take a delimited string and build an object from it:

```
   const treeString = 'Parent::Child::GrandChild'; // input string
    const treeParts = treeString.split('::');  // split into levels
    
    var tree = []; // will contain the final tree for this input
    var count = 0; // input count
    var child = []; // variable to hold children we have processed
 
    // loop through input from lowest level (GrandChild) up to top level (Parent)
    for (var i = treeParts.length - 1; i>=0; i--) 
    {
      // Create a child element (for top level this will be added to Tree)
      child = {
             title: treeParts[i], 
             count: count, 
             child: [ child ] 
        };
    } 
// Finally add to tree
tree.push(child);
```

You would probably want to turn this into a function and call it for each element in your original object.